# Design PDA or CFG for the following language

Tags: automata

$L = \{wtw' \mid w,w' \in \{a, b\}^*, \hspace{0.3cm} |w|_a = |w'|_a, \hspace{0.3cm} |w|_b=2|w'|_b, \hspace{0.3cm} t\in\{c\}^* \}$.

> Note : $|w|_a$ means the number of $a$ in substring $w$.

To substring $w$, the number of symbol $a$ and $b$ is not relevant to each other.

It's also applied to substring $w'$.

To make matters worse, order of $a$ and $b$ (in both $w$ and $w'$) is not defined. So order can be anyway... It makes the problem harder for me.

I designed several PDAs but they resulted in contradiction.

So I tried to construct a CFG. But designing a CFG is more difficult for me.

Could you give me some hints to design PDA or CFG for the above language?

Comment: Shouldn't the number of $c$s be at least one? If you allow zero number of $c$s then how can we tell apart $w$ from $w'$? I am not sure but it seems in that case the language is not CF.

Comment: I typed correctly. # of $c$'s more than or equals to 0.
However could you construct PDA(or CFG) to accept language $L$ with substring $t$ has at least 1 $c$'s?
That would be great help for me.

Comment: @fade2black I think we can handle the case $|t| = 0$ by using the nondeterministic property of $NPDA$, like constructing a $NPDA$ for language $ww^r$ where we don't need a seperating symbol between $w$ and $w^r$.

Comment: @Karegar, But DPDAs are not equal to NPDAs. If OP accepts a NPDA, then you can construct one.

Comment: @fade2black Yes, that's why we can't necessarily construct a $DPDA$ for a $CFG$ grammar. Since it is mentioned that designing a $CFG$ is ok, I think $NPDA$ is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such grammar: the language is not context-free.

$L\cap a^*b^*ca^*b^* = \{a^nb^{2m}ca^nb^m\mid m,n\ge 1\}$.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I have a question. you commented $m, n \ge 1$. However $m, n \ge 0$ isn't it?